# Pythonic way to stop file validation

Tags: python, loops, control-flow

I am writing a script to validate csv files. I have several functions that do things like checking if a certain field is below some threshold, or check if there are any NaN values.

These functions return(True) if the checks are passed, return(False) otherwise.

I am trying to figure out the correct/pythonic way to stop processing once one of these checks fails & returns False.

I tried while True, but this only evaluates the last value returned in the loop. Any help is appreciated!

```
#I have functions that validate certain things in a csv file
#those functions return(True) if they pass the test, return(False) otherwise.

#I want to be able to call these functions and have the file stop 
#processing once a False is returned.

def function1():
    return(True)
def function2():
    return(True)
def function3():
    return(False)
def function4():
    return(True)

#works, but not pythonic.
checkpoint1 = function1()
if checkpoint1 == True:
    checkpoint2 = function2()
    if checkpoint2 == True:
            checkpoint3 = function3()
            if checkpoint3 == True:
                checkpoint4 = function4()
                if checkpoint4 == True:
                    print("all checkpoints passed")
                else:
                    print("Fail 4")
            else:
                print("Fail 3")
    else:
        print("Fail 2")
else:
    print("Fail 1")
```

Comment: Sidenote: `return` is a statement, not a function, so remove the unnecessary parentheses: `return True`.

Comment: You *can* remove the parentheses; there's no harm in using them, though. `True` and `(True)` are two expressions with the same value.

Comment: @chepner Yeah but it looks like a function call *`return()`, which can be confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the functions into a single list, then iterate over that list to call each, breaking early if one fails.

```
for i, f in enumerate([function1, function2, function3, function4], start=1):
    if not f():
        print(f"Fail {i}")
        break
else:
    print("all checkpoints passed")
```

If you didn't want the output, you could simply use `all`:

```
if all(f() for f in [function1, function2, function3, function4]):
    print("all checkpoints passed")
else:
    print("One checkpoint failed")
```

Comment: Nice, didn't realize you could iterate over a list of functions like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of dealing with such a problem.

The easiest is, to just create a function for all the combined checking, and exit it early once you detect a problem.

```py
def validate_file(args):
    if not function1():
       print("Fail 1")
       return False

    if not function2():
       print("Fail 2")
       return False

    if not function3():
       print("Fail 3")
       return False

    if not function3():
       print("Fail 3")
       return False

    print("all checkpoints passed")
    return True
```

Then you can just call the function `validate_file`, and it returns `False` if some checks failed or not. This way, you don't have the deeply nested indentation.

---

Probably more Pythonic would be to use exceptions.
Instead of returning `True` or `False`, the individual functions can raise exceptions if there is a problem. And you can then catch those if there was an error. E.g. something like that:

```py
def function2():
   # code
   some_check_failed = True
   if some_check_failed:
      raise FileNotFoundError("fail 2")
   # code

try:
    function1()
    function2()
    function3()
    function4()
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    print(f"File not found: {e}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Unknown error: {e}")
```

Answer (score 1):

If the else statements where you print which function fails are not necessary, you could also just place everything into an if statement:

```
if f1() and f2() and f3() and f4(): print(all checkpoints passed)
```

If one of the conditions fail, the other conditions will not execute. For example, this code:

```
def f1():
    print(1)
    return True
def f2():
    print(2)
    return False
def f3():
    print(3)
    return True

if f1() and f2() and f3():
    print("Hi")
else:
    print("Bye")
```

Has the following output: `1 2 Bye`

Since f3() did not run because f2() failed.

If you want to be descriptive on which condition failed (which is always great), you can put the logging/print statements inside the actual function that checks the condition.

For example:

```
def f3():
    #If f3 fails
    print("F3 condition failed")

    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "Fail x" messages are replacements for more descriptive errors, you can use a dict to store them mapped to their functions, then iterate and print if needed.

```
checkpoints = {
    function1: "Fail 1",
    function2: "Fail 2",
    function3: "Fail 3",
    function4: "Fail 4",
    }

for f in checkpoints:
    if not f():
        print(checkpoints[f])
        break
else:  # no break
    print('all checkpoints passed')
```

Output: `Fail 3`

If you're using Python 3.6 or older, `dict` isn't guaranteed to preserve order, so instead you could use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) or a list of tuples `(function, error)`.